# NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Tags: python

Hello guys now I know there are solutions on stack overflow I just did not understand them, here is my code

```
enter code here
import urllib.request import urlopen

def read_text():
quotes = open(r"C:\Users\LEON\Desktop\python\Swear_words.txt")
contents_of_file = quotes.read()
print(contents_of_file)
quotes.close()
check_profanity(contents_of_file)


def check_profanity(text_to_check):
connection = 
urllib.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/q=s"+text_to_check)
output = connection.read()


read_text()
```

error
   NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Comment: Your import statement does not include `urllib` itself. You will need an extra import statement for it.

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code? You've lost all the indentation, and it's not clear if you have one `import` line at the top or two that have mistakenly been merged together. If the import is `from urllib.request import urlopen` then I think Klaus has the issue identified.

Comment: Either `import urllib` and leave code as it is, OR fix the import to `from urllib.request ...` and change the code to simply `urlopen("...")`. And fix the code format

Answer (score 3):

The import statement itself has incorrect syntax. It should/could be

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

Then the 3rd last line doesn't need the `urllib` prefix

```
urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/q=s"+text_to_check)
```

Comment: I tried and I still get an error only this time its "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"

Comment: I think you need a question mark after the slash, you could also reformat a bit for Python 3.6 or later to use an f-string `urlopen(f"http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=s{text_to_check}")`

Comment: OK. There must be some special characters in the string somewhere that are being translated. Glad it worked for you.